# Workflow web service call looping

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, web-services, loop

I have a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow that is calling a web service method I have created and hosted on a server.

The workflow in the browser workflow history seems to be triggered only once, however the web service method seems to be entering an infinite loop as it is logging to text file continuously and the workflow is never terminated.

What could the problem be?

Is it something wrong with the way workflow manager was registered maybe?

Comment: Are you calling this web service in a loop in workflow?

Comment: no it is just one call .. the exact same workflow/webservice method works fine on a different environment...

Comment: Could it have been caused because I added a second web frontend to the workflow manager farm and so it now has two endpoints?

Comment: Try adding history log before calling the web service and after calling web service action...Or you have added this workflow on item change and item updated multiple times?

Comment: no it is on item create

Comment: Could it have been caused because I added a second web frontend to the workflow manager farm and so it now has two endpoints?  Should it be on both web  front ends or not?

Comment: I am not sure if that's causing this issue or not.

Comment: I logged history before and after, it only makes 1 webservice call.. but that method call seems to be looping.. I do not have any recursions in m code however.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within the web service. It boileld down to two problems:
 1. not enough RAM on server
 2. too many ExecuteQuery calls

I refacotred the code to have less ExecuteQueries and it worked